# Could not resolve view with name error Spring MVC 4 + Apache Tiles 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am getting an errror when trying to integrate apache tiles 3 with Spring MVC 4. Please help me with this situation. Idea is to create pages that get dynamically updated using Apache Tiles. I have checked the dependencies and they all seem fine. I think my configuration is either missing something or the controller is failing to recognize the tiles configuration file.

Please help me with this. I am fairly new to developing Spring MVC and Apache Tiles applications. Please suggest what could have gone wrong with this code.

**Config class**

```
package com.naveen.PizzaPlace.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.naveen.PizzaPlace")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    /**
     * Configure TilesConfigurer.
     */
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/tiles.xml" });
    tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
    return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    /**
     * Configure ViewResolvers to deliver preferred views.
     */
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    TilesViewResolver viewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>PizzaPlace</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.naveen.PizzaPlace</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <!-- Base Definition -->
    <definition name="app.default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Pizza Place application" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <!-- Home Page -->
    <definition name="app.homepage" extends="base-definition">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**controller**

```
package com.naveen.PizzaPlace.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String defaultPages() {
    return "app.homepage";
    }
}
```

**error trace**

```
Jul 18, 2016 8:21:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/PizzaPlace] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'app.homepage' in servlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'app.homepage' in servlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: A small doubt as I am not familiar with Apache tile, still you have specified as <definition name="app.homepage" extends="base-definition">, but the base-definiation is not defined(it's app-default) .Could you please change and try again ?

Comment: Yeah, that was the mistake! I have corrected it! Thank you! **Answer is : app.homepage should extend app.default**

Comment: It's a good news, please accept it as valid answer if it resolves your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified as , but the base-definiation is not defined(it's app-default) .It should either extend app-default or app-default should be changed as app-base